# Confuse about high DPI PC device's resolution in css

Tags: css, screen-resolution, dpi

I have a Surface Pro 3 device, which recommend resolution is 2160x1440

But when I try to get resolution using javascript `window.screen.width` and `window.screen.height`

the result is 1440x960;

Why the Microsoft doesn't show its true resolution, and why the result is 1440x960?

Answer (score 0):

It's because CSS pixels are not equal to Device pixels.